Elementor, Blocksy and any other plugin stuck on loading screem
I just make my own wordpress server with my dedicated server, and after installing elementor or blocksy i get stuck on loading screen on the editor, is that caused by my server config or anything else, how to fix it?

I already grant the access with chown command to www-data, did i do something wrong or miss something

Welcome! Look at your error logs on the server. That should tell you what's going on. Make sure define('WP_DEBUG') is set to true in your wp-config.php as well.

Hi @disinfor , i already enable the wp-debug, and i can't find anything wrong, i already try to reinstall my web server and change it from nginx to apache and it still happened
